# Hello World compiling error in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I try to compile HelloWorld on my Mac.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I run from the terminal:

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
```

and I get

```
error: error reading /Users/gioelelamanno/Library/Java/Extensions/algs4.jar; 
cannot read zip file 1 error
```

Instead Eclispse compiles and run without problems.
How can I fix it?

Comment: which version of Java do you have installed on your mac? `java -version`. Have you downloaded all the updates? Seems there is a corrupted library in you Library. Since you are just doing an HelloWorld, removing the library should solve you problem, but don't delete it (a backup is always preferred in this cases).

Comment: java version "1.6.0_45"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely, the JAR file `algs4.jar` is corrupt. Either remove it from the classpath or get another copy if required for future compilation. The JAR file can be downloaded [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/algs4.jar)

Comment: Thank you a lot, downloading algs4.jar and stdlib.jar worked nicely.
But when I try to run the Helloworld.class I get:
$java HelloWorld.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    HelloWorld/class

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld.class
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Ah ok sorry my stupidity the right command was:
$ java HelloWorld  (without .class)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the .jar file within eclipse. Once you save it, then you should be able to view it in the console. In this case, the terminal. I had this same issue. This is how I resolved it.